# Problem is finding second highest values in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

Aim:
**To find the second smallest value of the sorted array in VB.NET.**

Procedure:

1. Start the program.
2. Assign  input values for an Array.
3. Sort the input of an array by using Sort method.
4. Find  the second smallest value of  the sorted array .
5. Show the sorted array and second smallest value of an array.
6. Stop the program

'''Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim n(10) As Integer 'Declaration n in array in integer format'
    Dim i, j As Integer  'Declaration i,j in integer format'
    Dim second_small As Integer
    second_small = 0
    Dim small As Integer
    small = 0
    For i = 0 To 10 'first condition check the statement looping for the 10 time'
        Console.WriteLine(" Enter the value for array value[{0}] : ", i)  'user input array values'
        n(i) = Console.ReadLine()  ' store the values in n of arry' 
    Next i
    For j = 0 To 10 'for array number'
        Console.WriteLine("Array value({0}) = {1}", j, n(j))
    Next j
    Console.WriteLine("Lowest Number To Higher Number")
    System.Array.Sort(n)
    For Each str As Integer In n
        Console.WriteLine(str)
    Next
    small = n(-1)
    For i = 1 To 10 Step 1
        If (small > n(i)) Then
            second_small = small
            small = n(i)
        End If
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("Second smallest element in array is: {0}", second_small)
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: well, you have your array sorted, from the smaller to the higher. Do you really need the last loop?

Comment: There's no need to "find" the largest or smallest item if you have already sorted your array. You know exactly where they are. You only need to search for something if you don't know where it is. Such searches are usually performed on unsorted arrays. If you are told to sort an array or list as part of a learning exercise, it usually has to be done by implementing an algorithm yourself rather than using the inbuilt method. To use an inbuilt sort and then a manual search is weird and pointless, so I'd double-check that that's actually what you have to do.

Comment: @user18387401 yes you are right we can easily find out the second minimum value in array but the process needed to find short the values in array after find the second small value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine("Second smallest element in array is: {0}", n(1))`
array values are stored in `n` values so the second smallest values are stored in 1 area.

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the array, you can select the first two elements after sorting. A more efficient way (arguably) is what you're trying to do with the last loop, which is not quite correct as it stands now.